# Insert into table using Oracle apps alert

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps

I have created an alert in Oracle apps that is using a procedure to insert data from table into custom table.

When I try to execute the alert and make sure it is working, the data is inserted into the table that the form is based on it and not inserted into the custom table.

Would any one help me ?

Procedure code:

```
procedure alert_insert 
  (mo_number varchar2, creation_date varchar2, created_by varchar2, description varchar2) 
is 
begin 
  insert into xx_custom_alerts_b 
    (numberr, creation_date, created_by , descriptiion) 
  values 
    (mo_number, creation_date, created_by, description); 
  commit; 
end alert_insert;
```

Comment: can u provide ur procedure information and Alert details ...

Comment: procedure alert_insert (mo_number varchar2 , creation_date varchar2 , created_by varchar2 , description varchar2) is
    begin
      insert into xx_custom_alerts_b ( numberr , creation_date , created_by , descriptiion)
      values
      (mo_number , creation_date , created_by , description);
      commit;
      end alert_insert ;

Comment: can u add above code in your question .. it's not comprehensible in comments

Comment: Not related to your question, but - I'd suggest you to rename procedure parameters so that their names aren't exactly the same as table column names. For example, you could use PAR_CREATION_DATE or CREATION_DATE_IN or P_CREATION_DATE or ... Keeping the same name will (sooner or later) cause problems.

Comment: I found that some of oracle tables are not allowed to insert into them from alerts , and this table is one of them .